# How can I prove that early termination in an MDP state is valid?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I have an MDP $M$ with transition function $p$, states $S$ and a state $s^0 \in S$. $s^0$ has the property that both the most optimistic trajectory (highest expected reward) and the most pessimistic trajectory (lowest expected reward) starting from $s^0$ have $0$ expected discounted return.

Intuitively, once we enter $s^0$, it does not matter what we do, the expected reward in the end is $0$.

I would like to prove that the optimal policy in another MDP, $M'$, will also be the optimal policy for $M$. $M'$ is the same as $M$ except with $s^0$ as an absorbing state (sink state with output $0$).

I am fairly convinced that this is the case. Loosely speaking, I would like to show this by computing the expected return of a policy in both $M$ and $M'$, and showing that they are equal. Ideally, I would compute the expected return of a policy $\pi$ in both $M$ and $M'$, by multiplying the probability of each trajectory with the value of the rewards along it, and taking a sum over all trajectories.

Intuitively, if $t$ is a trajectory in $M$ induced by $\pi$, then $t$ is also induced in $M'$ "with the same probability", and they have the same discounted return. Of course, many different trajectories in $M$ may map to a single trajectory in $M'$, as $M'$ has $s^0$ as an absorbing state. However, once we enter $s^0$ in either MDP, the expected return that follows is $0$ for any policy in both MDPs (in $M$, because of the property of $s^0$ that bounds returns following it with $0$ from above and below, and in $M'$ by definition).

My immediate difficulty is that there are infinitely many trajectories, and it makes no sense to speak of a "probability of a trajectory".

Comment: I am not sure what structuring any sum of rewards in M as a formal structure would help with, since you would write it out formally, then refer to the special constraints and say it was equal to zero. Not sure what you expect to gain by constructing the formula?

Comment: can't you just replace the MDP connected to $s_0$ with just a self loop?